# Problem in my Laravel blade with variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem with my blade. I get this error when I run my project:

my blade codes:

```
@foreach(\App\Category::all()->where('parent' , $product->categories->where('parent' , '0')->first()->id )->first() as $category)
    <option data-id="{{ $category->id }}" value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ in_array($category->id , $product->categories->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

and the error is shown:

> ErrorException
>
> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: F:\Projects\Laravel Projects\NilfamShop\laravel\resources\views\admin\products\edit.blade.php)

Comment: `first` can return `null` ... and why would you be trying to iterate a single item?

Comment: you're right it was my fault. thanks @lagbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the mistake :

```
$product->categories->where('parent' , '0')->first()->id )->first()
```

Maybe you can call instead :

```
 $product->categories->where('parent' , '0')->first()->id
```